# Displaying the logs with Behavex Framework

Tags: python-behave

I have a question with respect to logging mechanism with BehaveX Framework . We are using Behave Framework and evaluating Behavex .

```
Our requirement is to run multiple test cases some thing like this :

behavex  folder\test1.feature
behavex  folder\test2.feature
behavex  folder\test3.feature
behavex  folder\test4.feature
behavex  folder\test15.feature
```

By default logs will go to  DIR\output directory . After executing one test case, the output directory  is getting overwritten with the next test case results .

```
Can the test results be logged something like this :
DIR\output\test1\report.html
DIR\output\test2\report.html
DIR\output\test3\report.html
```

Basically it should follow this format \output\testcasename\report.html

Can this enhancement be accommodated with next Version of BehaveX Framework

```
NOTE:
```

We don't want to use -output option as it is complicating things for us . We Execute 100 test cases and it is not possible to mention -output for each Test case .

Comment: The problem is that when we execute multiple test cases the output directory is always overwritten . Say , when we execute TC1 and start TC2 , the logs will be over written .